# Android Spinner Inside RecyclerView Get Current View When Selected

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I have a RecyclerView implementing a LinearLayout of CardViews through an adapter. Inside each CardView, I have a spinner. What I need to do is get the CardViews position when a spinner is selected. Ex.. if I have 10 CardViews in a list on the screen with a spinner in each, and a select a value from the spinner in the 5th item, I need to get that 5th position as well as the selected value.

I'm able to get the selected value just fine. The issue is with getting the CardViews position. The CardViews are being generated from an ArrayList.

I will include my code below along with an image of the desired results. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

[image]

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
public class PopularAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PopularAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    PopularFragment mPopularFragment;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<GameData> gameDataArr = new ArrayList<GameData>();
    private String userId;

    public PopularAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GameData> gameDataArr, PopularFragment mPopularFragment, String userId) {
        mContext = context;
        this.gameDataArr = gameDataArr;
        this.mPopularFragment = mPopularFragment;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView title;
        public ImageView thumbnail;
        private CardView mCardView;
        PopularFragment mPopularFragment;
        Spinner mGameSpinner;
        LinearLayout mSpinnerLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View view, final PopularFragment mPopularFragment, final String userId) {
            super(view);
            this.mPopularFragment = mPopularFragment;
            mSpinnerLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_layout);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_main_img);
            mCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_cardview);
            mCardView.setOnClickListener(this);

            mGameSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.game_spinner_options);
            mGameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                    //String ASIN = gameDataArr.get(position).getAmazonId();
                    System.out.println(parent.getId());     // <--- prints the same value for each item.
                    if(userId == null){
                        Toast.makeText(mPopularFragment.getActivity(), "You must be logged in.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    FirebaseDbHelper mFirebaseDbHelper = new FirebaseDbHelper();
                    if(position == 0){
                        // remove from db
                       // mFirebaseDbHelper.removeOwnedGame(ASIN, userId);
                    } else if(position == 1){
                        // add to owned games
                       // mFirebaseDbHelper.addOwnedGame(ASIN, userId);
                    } else {
                        // add to wishlist games
                      //  mFirebaseDbHelper.addWishlistGame(ASIN, userId);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("click: " + getPosition());
            //mPopularFragment.openGameActivity(getPosition());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public PopularAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        System.out.println("parent: " + parent);
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new PopularAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView, mPopularFragment, userId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PopularAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        GameData game = gameDataArr.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(game.getTitle());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(game.getFeatImgUrl()).resize(160, 200).into(holder.thumbnail);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return gameDataArr.size();
    }


}
```

**CardView**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_cardview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_main_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/game_spinner_options"
                    android:entries="@array/game_dropdown"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>

                <Button
                    android:text="Buy Now"
                    android:id="@+id/game_buy_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Popular Fragment**

```
public class PopularFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.popular_recyclerView)
    RecyclerView mPopularRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    private ArrayList<GameData> gamesArray = new ArrayList<GameData>();
    ApiResultsObject apiResults;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
    private String userId;

    public PopularFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        // bus instance
        MyBus.getInstance().register(this);

        // get api url
        // trigger async task
        // use results
        String amazonApiUrl = getAmazonApiUrl();
        if(amazonApiUrl != null){
            new AmazonAsyncTask().execute(amazonApiUrl);
        }

        //get firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        //get current user
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        //add a auth listener
        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    System.out.println("User logged in. Game activity.");
                    userId = user.getUid();

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    System.out.println("User not logged in. Game activity");

                }
            }
        };

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    private String getAmazonApiUrl() {
        String amazonApiUrl = "";
        AmazonQuery amazonQuery = new AmazonQuery("ItemSearch");
        amazonApiUrl = amazonQuery.buildUrl();
        return amazonApiUrl;
    }

    private void setData(ApiResultsObject data) {
        gamesArray = data.getGamesArray();
        if (data != null) {
            mAdapter = new PopularAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), gamesArray, this, userId);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mPopularRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mPopularRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }
    }



    @Subscribe
    public void onAsyncTaskResults(BrowseAsyncTaskResult event) {
        apiResults = event.getResults();
        if (apiResults != null) {
            setData(apiResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        MyBus.getInstance().unregister(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (authListener != null) {
            auth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an OnClickListener on mGameSpinner in your onBindViewHolder().

```
onBindViewHolder(final PopularAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position)
```

You can then store/use the position parameter as it will be the index into your gameArray for that particular spinner.  You can then use that index to grab the spinner's currently selected value and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: This works with an OnItemSelectedListener. Thanks for the help!

Comment: OnItemSelectedListener gives position of the spinner values , but what about position of recyclerview ?

Comment: YOU cannot set OnClickListener to spinner

Comment: @karthikkolanji  Why not?  I'm pretty sure I was able to back when I posted my answer and it worked fine.  Granted, it is not the optimal way as I have realized since then.  So what do you mean?

Comment: I tried ... It throws error ." You cannot set OnClickListener() to spinner"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set a tag for each view in the RV through the holder in `onBindViewHolder`. Something like:

`holder.itemView.setTag(game.getId());`

The game's Id should be one of the data points in the `ArrayList` you passed into the `Adpater`. So it'd be easier to add a `getId()` method to your `game` object.

Once you have an integer Id to call on that's unique to each game in the list, you can simply find that Id within the Spinner's `onItemSelectedListener` with:

`int ID = (int) holder.itemView.getTag();`

Then you can use `ID` within your if-else statements to know which game within your card list the spinner is selected for.

Answer (score 0):

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final LanguagesAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

```
    holder.edit_language_name.setText(edit_languageDetails_ArrayList.get(position).getEt_language_name());
     sp_langage_rating=edit_languageDetails_ArrayList.get(position).getEt_language_ratings();
    String ss=sp_langage_rating;


    if(sp_langage_rating != null) {
      if(sp_langage_rating.equals("Beginner"))
      {
          adapterLanguage = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context, R.layout.my_spinner_items, strarray_language);
          adapterLanguage.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          holder.sp_languages.setAdapter(adapterLanguage);
      }
      else if(sp_langage_rating.equals("Intermediate")) {

          adapterLanguage = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context, R.layout.my_spinner_items, strarray_language1);
          adapterLanguage.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          holder.sp_languages.setAdapter(adapterLanguage);

      }else if(sp_langage_rating.equals("Expert")){
          adapterLanguage = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context, R.layout.my_spinner_items, strarray_language2);
          adapterLanguage.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          holder.sp_languages.setAdapter(adapterLanguage);
      }


    }else{
        adapterLanguage = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context, R.layout.my_spinner_items, strarray_language);
        adapterLanguage.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.sp_languages.setAdapter(adapterLanguage);
    }




    Log.d("print","yes");

}
```